# jQuery noob: change Display of one element when another is enabled

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made an attempt at changing the CSS of an element `display: block;` when another div is enabled..

[Here is a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GKvmz/10/).

What am I doing wrong?

[Website example](http://www.euroworker.no/): click FILTER MENY and select one of the filters. When the div "DU SØKER" is enabled, Filter Meny should stay open, when Du Søker is not enanbled (remove your filter choice) it should return to what it was doing previously.

Comment: if you're just doing a show-hide just use jquery's show()/hide() functions to save you the trouble :)

Comment: Come to that, avoid modifying CSS directly at all, modify the classes and let your CSS decide what that means.

Comment: I already did a show hide on this, basically it's a filter menu, and when user selects a filter, it refreses the page, and adds a div with class `expandResults` so I want to tell the browser that if that div is there, tell this div to always display, if not, return to what I've already set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First line in your example must look like:

```
if($('.box.expandResults')) {
```

missed a parenthesis and a dot.

Comment: Thanks, it works when the div is ensbled, but when I disable it again, it still remains..

Comment: How can I tell the else to just return to what it was originally?